# What is The Optimal Size for An Entity In App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

Looking for insider information here.

I have a large list of MD5 hashes that I want to store in the datastore. The list is large enough that I must use multiple entities to store it. This means I have to break up my list into smaller lists and store them individually.

To do this, I have a simple Model which can store and retrieve an arbitrarily long list of hashes:

```
class HashList(nbd.Model):
  MAX_LENGTH = 100

  zlist = ndb.BlobProperty()
  keyword = ndb.StringProperty()
  index = ndb.IntegerProperty()

  @classproperty
  def StoreList(cls, keyword, long_list):
    entities = []
    index = 0
    for i in range(0, len(long_list), cls.MAX_LENGTH):
      zlist = zlib.compress('\n'.join(long_list[i:i+cls.MAX_LENGTH]))
      entities.append(cls(keyword=keyword, index=index, zlist=zlist))
      index += 1
    ndb.put_multi(entities)

  @classproperty
  def GetList(cls, keyword):
    unpack = lambda e: zlib.decompress(e.zlist).split()
    q = cls.query(cls.keyword == keyword).order(cls.index)
    return list(itertools.chain(*q.map(unpack)))
```

Suppose I know the list has 1,000,000 MD5 hashes. The above code would produce 10,000 entities each with their zlist property being a little less 2k in size (based on my own simple testing).

Basically, I'm wonder what the optimal value for MAX_LENGTH is. If MAX_LENGTH gets larger, then the entity size gets larger. Should I push toward 1MB per entity (~40,000 MD5 hashes)? Is 100 too small? Is 1000 better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should go as big as possible - 1Mb. I see no reason why not: this way you minimize cost.

OTOH, since you store MD5s as blob, maybe you should look into [blobstore](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/overview#Writing_Files_to_the_Blobstore).

**Edit:**

As @Guido implicitly noted, GAE is a distributed system, so multiple writes could happen in parallel so thay can be potentially faster.

Comment: I had read someplace that AE was optimized for smaller entities. I wish I could find the link. But this is what drove my question. So, I'm afraid that storing many 1MB entities would slow down performance.

Comment: Since you are saving the same amount of unindexed data, I don't see a way that one large entity would be slower than multiple ones of smaller size.

Comment: You really have to measure it.

Comment: Hmm, on a second thought, GAE does this in parallel to multiple servers so this __could__ be faster.

Comment: @Guido: judging from article on index building, call to put() returns before entity is actually fully written DB (index is still building). Does async put in this case make this parallel put any faster? Or is multi-put enough?

Comment: Thanks. This answer helps. If I simply have to measure it to see, then it seems there is no rule of thumb such as "don't use a bunch of 1MB entities."

Comment: I don't think explicit async calls make anything faster. Remember that a sync call is always implemented as an async call plus a wait operation, and that any async calls not waited for at all are waited for once the request handling ends, before the response is sent back to the client.

Comment: This was one of the unclear things for me: is response held until all async operations are finished even if not waited for. Docs are not really clear on this.